# How to mirror an entity vertically using .Net in BricsCad or AutoCad

Tags: c#, matrix, mirror, autocad-plugin

I have the following matrix:

```
_AcGe.Matrix3d acMatrix3dMirror = _AcGe.Matrix3d.Mirroring(_AcGe.Point3d.Origin);
```

I am new to using matries and I can see from the documentation that I can use:

- Line
- Plane
- Point

What I have is not quite right. My mirror line needs to basically be 0,0,0 vertically up the screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out:

```
// Mirror vertically
_AcGe.Line3d oMirrorLine = new _AcGe.Line3d(new _AcGe.Point3d(0, 0, 0), new _AcGe.Point3d(0, 1, 0));
_AcGe.Matrix3d acMatrix3dMirror = _AcGe.Matrix3d.Mirroring(oMirrorLine);
```

This is a useful [resource](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-3ed5.htm,topicNumber=d0e22413) for information about transformations.